# AWS Amplify AppSync IAM 401

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm getting `GraphQLError: Request failed with status code 401`

I followed the automatic configuration instructions from:

https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide#automated-configuration-with-cli

I tried looking, but there are a lack of resources for IAM. It looks like everything should be setup automatically, and done with the Amplify CLI after I put in the IAM access key and secret.

Is further setup required? Here is my code:

```
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import aws_config from "../../aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(aws_config);

const ListKeywords = `query ListKeywords {
  listKeyword {
    keyword {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}`;

const loop = async () => {
  const allKeywords = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(ListKeywords));
}
```

Could it also be because my GraphQL resolvers are not setup yet for ListKeywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `~/.aws/credentials` and now it's working.

Looks like even if you have project specific configuration via Amplify's command line tools or `~/.awsmobile/aws-config.js`, it still relies on `~/.aws`

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid ~/.aws from overriding your Amplify config? This is breking my app on people's systems who have a ~/.aws directory configured

Answer (score 4):

If you're using IAM as the Authorization type on your AppSync API then the issue is the Cognito Role being used with the Auth category when invoking `Amplify.configure()` isn't granted permissions for GraphQL operations. It needs something like this attached:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "appsync:GraphQL"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:appsync:us-west-2:123456789012:apis/YourGraphQLApiId/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html

Comment: It should have AWSAppSyncAdministrator permissions. Is this the same IAM user that's setup with awsmobile configure? https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/quick_start#install-aws-mobile-cli

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I've been struggling with this for a while and found that if I add the API and use IAM as the auth method I need to add 'auth' to the schema too.

See below:

```
type TimeLapseCamera @model 
@auth(rules: [
  { allow: private, provider: iam }
])
{
...
}
```

I just tested this and my web page is successfully adding a record.

Note to other comment; I do not have AWS at all in this - its a simple VUE app with Amplify.