# Getting issues after adding amazon cognito to my react-native expo tsx project

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, react-hooks, amazon-cognito

Hi Guys I keep getting the error below after I  added  aws auth  to my react-native application using `amplify add auth` any help on fixing the below error  will be appreciated

```
Object {    
  "data": Object {},
  "errors": Array [
    [GraphQLError: Request failed with status code 401],
  ],
}
```

Comment: This thread should resolve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394268/aws-amplify-appsync-iam-401

Comment: That treat failed to resolve the issues I am facing @Lavande anymore suggestion

Comment: The thread didn't resolve my issues anymore suggestion @Lavande